# How can I apply a filter to remove reverberation with python?

Tags: python, impulse-response, deconvolution, self-study

I am developing an algorithm that automates the processing of audio files for the assembly of datasets of machine learning models.

Among the steps to be followed for the processing of the files is to apply filters to remove noise, reverb, etc..

For now I am only going to focus on my main concern, the reverberation. Searching the internet I found that it could be eliminated with a deconvolution function that needs two elements: the audio signal and the IR or pulse response.

With this in mind I have this function to apply a filter that eliminates the reverb:

```py
import librosa
import numpy as np
import scipy.fft as fft
from scipy import signal
import soundfile as sf

def rm_reverb(signal_reverberado, IR):
    signal_desconvolucionado = fft.ifft(
        signal.fftconvolve(signal_reverberado, respuesta_al_impulso.conj(), mode='same'))
    
    return np.real(signal_desconvolucionado)
```

But now I need the IR which I do not have. So my current efforts are based on investigating how to know the IR of the file to be processed. For now I have 3 possible solutions:

1. Synthesize the IR (I don't know how).
2. do a blind deconvolution (which I don't know how to do either).
3. deduce the average IR based on all the files used for the dataset (which I think I more or less know how to do).
   So far the third option seems the most feasible and easy to implement although I have doubts about the final quality of the dataset.

For solution 3 I have this code:

```py
def average_IR(signals): #array to signals
    long_min = min(len(signal) for signal in signals)
    
    IR_result = np.zeros(long_min)
    
    for signal in signals:
        IR_result += signal[:long_min]
    
    IR_result /= len(signals)
    
    return IR_result
```

In short, the question is how can I deduct the IR to eliminate the reverberation and if I am on the right or wrong way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dereverberation is VERY difficult.

> Synthesize the IR (I don't know how).

Won't work. For deconvolution you need the exact impulse response and no simulation in existence is good enough for that. Also the amount and accuracy of the acoustic and geometrical data that you need will be prohibitive.

> do a blind deconvolution (which I don't know how to do either).

Very difficult to do and unlikely to work. Most existing algorithms have been to de-blur images. I doubt that it can work on reverberation.

> deduce the average IR based on all the files used for the dataset (which I think I more or less know how to do).

Won't work. You need the exact impulse response for each track. The "average" impulse response will not deconvolve anything and chances are the average will contain a lot less reverb than the individual samples since the reverb tail tends to be very decorrelated.

> signal_desconvolucionado = fft.ifft(      signal.fftconvolve(signal_reverberado, respuesta_al_impulso.conj(), mode='same'))

That won't work either. You need to convolve the INVERSE of the room impulse response, no with the room impulse response itself. The inverse is very difficult to calculate and in general it's non-causal and badly behaved.

A room impulse response has 1000s (or 10s of 1000s) of samples and its very complicated. The corresponding transfer function has a very complicated fine structure including a lot of deep and narrow dips or zeros which makes it very difficult to invert.

Most algorithms for dereverberation do a running estimate of whether something is more direct or more reverb and than run a time variant Wiener filter based on this estimate. Another approach are neural networks and machine learning. Typically this gets rid of some of the reverb but it also induces non-trivial artifacts.

This all needs to be tuned to your specific application and requirements: Algorithm that work well on speech are completely unacceptable for music. Optimizing speech intelligibility for a voice assistant has different requirements that optimizing for a human listener.

Comment: Based on your answer and discarding the proposals that I raise in my question I consider using a ML model. For those interested in this option, I am using the UVR5 library, you can get it in [this repo](https://github.com/Anjok07/ultimatevocalremovergui).Notice that this repo is not only the library, it also has a GUI, the model used for UVR is `VR-DeEchoDeReverb.pth`. In the near future I will publish in my github a fork of this repo to be able to use the library and to be able to facilitate the work to future people with the same doubt as mine.

Answer (score 1):

[This page](https://www.huddlestone.es/en/reverberation/) has a nice explanation of what reverb is and how to reduce its recording if you're able to take steps while recording.

I'm assuming you already have the recording and are now trying to fix it up after the fact.

That page has the following nice image:

[image: Picture from huddlestone.es website.]

which suggests that a first approach to identifying your reverberation impulse response is just as a simple damped exponential:

$$
h[n] = e^{-n/\tau}
$$
where $\tau$ is your time constant that determines how long the reverberation happens for. The trick will be to determine your $\tau$ empirically (by trying different values).

Comment: I don't think that's a useful model: while the envelope of the impulse response follows an exponential decay (at least for narrow enough frequency bands), the fine structure is very complicated and so is the fine structure frequency response. Also the only solution they offer is acoustic treatment of the recording environment. That's certainly useful but in most cases completely impractical.

Comment: @Hilmar Agreed!  Just trying to start them on the exploration. :-)